# Using LoadingCache with CacheManager

Tags: java, spring, caching, guava, cachemanager

I use next one for my custom cache manager:

```
SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
GuavaCache myCache = new GuavaCache("telescope", CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build());
cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(myCache));
return cacheManager;
```

Now I want to use LoadingCache, because I need the method `refreshAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)` instead of `expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)`.

I can't put LoadingCache to GuavaCache and then set this GuavaCache into SimpleCacheManager.

Which implementations I need to use?

Comment: Why can't you pass a `LoadingCache` to `GuavaCache`? A quick read of `GuavaCache`'s [javadoc] states it takes a `com.google.common.cache.Cache` which `LoadingCache` extends.

Comment: Use CaffeinCache instead of GuavaCache. You can set them in the cache manager and also have a refreshAfterWrite with those.